# Smart way to check super-class

Tags: java, class, comparison, superclass

```
public  boolean isUserControled(){      
        return action.getClass().getSuperclass().toString().equals("class logic.UserBehaviour");
}
```

I think this piece of code is pretty self-explanatory. Is there a smarter way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unless you specifically want to check only the very first superclass, it would be better to use:

```
return (action instanceof logic.UserBehavior);
```

Your method would be better with this:

```
action.getClass().getSuperClass().name().equals("logic.UserBehavior");
```

The call to `toString()` is not the best idea.

Or better yet, as posted by [Ulrik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/685961/ulrik):

```
action.getClass().getSuperClass() == logic.UserBehavior.class
```

Comment: "name equal" isn't strictly correct. simpler and better with `==` (see Ulrik's answer)

Comment: I agree and hadn't though about it initially, (+1)'d his answer already.

Answer (score 13):

`(action instanceof logic.UserBehaviour)` will return true if action is an object of a type that extends UserBehavior.

An excerpt from http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html

> The Type Comparison Operator
>   instanceof
>
> The instanceof operator compares an
>   object to a specified type. You can
>   use it to test if an object is an
>   instance of a class, an instance of a
>   subclass, or an instance of a class
>   that implements a particular
>   interface.
>
> The following program, InstanceofDemo,
>   defines a parent class (named Parent),
>   a simple interface (named
>   MyInterface), and a child class (named
>   Child) that inherits from the parent
>   and implements the interface.

```
class InstanceofDemo {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Parent obj1 = new Parent();
    Parent obj2 = new Child();

    System.out.println("obj1 instanceof Parent: " + (obj1 instanceof Parent));
    System.out.println("obj1 instanceof Child: " + (obj1 instanceof Child));
    System.out.println("obj1 instanceof MyInterface: " + (obj1 instanceof MyInterface));
    System.out.println("obj2 instanceof Parent: " + (obj2 instanceof Parent));
    System.out.println("obj2 instanceof Child: " + (obj2 instanceof Child));
    System.out.println("obj2 instanceof MyInterface: " + (obj2 instanceof MyInterface));
  }
}

class Parent{}
class Child extends Parent implements MyInterface{}
interface MyInterface{}
```

Output:

```
obj1 instanceof Parent: true
obj1 instanceof Child: false
obj1 instanceof MyInterface: false
obj2 instanceof Parent: true
obj2 instanceof Child: true
obj2 instanceof MyInterface: true
```

When using the instanceof operator, keep in mind that null is not an instance of anything.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to check only the very first superclass:

```
return action.getClass().getSuperclass() == logic.UserBehavior.class;
```

Otherwise:

```
return (action instanceof logic.UserBehaviour);
```